# iis6 url redirecting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-6, url-routing

i always use iis 7 in my projects till now. and my url rewriting system was redirecting 404 errors to a pagenotfound.aspx page in iis7 then find the url mathces with the coming one and redirect it

forexample

if request is http://www.mysite.com/productname
i will redirect it to the http://www.mysite.com/products.aspx?id=33

but now i have to use iis 6 for my customer in my new project and i am wondering about if this method possible in iis 6 too? and can it be done with the same way or is there any difference if it is possible?

thanks

Comment: i just made 404 redirecting in iis 7 version and i want to know it is possible in iis6? and iis6 can execute the url: mysite.com/products without any additional url rewriting module?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Error in II6 pretty much work in exactly the same way.  Open the properties of the website, you will see a "Custom Errors" tab which will give you access to them.

If you're talking about "URL Rewrite" style module for IIS6, there is one called IIRF (Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter) which can [be found here](http://iirf.codeplex.com/).

**Edit** - I've never used IIRF, so can't comment on how similar or usable it is in comparison to the official URL Rewrite for IIS7

Comment: @ercan, Please confirm whether you're talking about inbuilt Custom Errors, or the additional URL Rewrite module?

Comment: i dont want to use any additional url rewrite module if it is possible i want to use only iis6 if it does everything i want

Comment: @ercan, the major difference that I'm aware of between IIS6 and IIS7 is that in IIS7 the custom errors are stored in the `web.config` file in the root of the web application. In IIS6 I *think* they have to be setup via the Admin tools.